# How to implement generic service and repository class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to have generic service and repository classes in my project. I wrote it this way, but I don't know if it is correct or not.

**BaseModel:**

```
 @MappedSuperclass
 @Data
public class AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Version
private int version;
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

public AbstractBaseEntity() {
    this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

}

**GenericService:**

```
public interface AbstractBaseService<T extends AbstractBaseEntity, ID extends Serializable>{
public abstract T save(T entity);
public abstract List<T> findAll(); // you might want a generic Collection if u prefer

public abstract Optional<T> findById(ID entityId);
public abstract T update(T entity);
public abstract T updateById(T entity, ID entityId);
public abstract void delete(T entity);
public abstract void deleteById(ID entityId);
// other methods u might need to be generic
```

}

Here I inherited from base service class and Autowired repository base classes.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractBaseServiceImpl<T extends AbstractBaseEntity, ID extends Serializable>
    implements AbstractBaseService<T, ID> {
@Autowired
private AbstractBaseRepository<T, ID> abstractBaseRepository;

protected abstract Class<T> getDomaimClass();

protected Class<T> domainClass = this.getDomaimClass();

@Override
public T save(T entity) {
    return (T) abstractBaseRepository.save(entity);
}

@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
    return abstractBaseRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Optional<T> findById(ID entityId) {
    return abstractBaseRepository.findById(entityId);
}

@Override
public T update(T entity) {
    return (T) abstractBaseRepository.save(entity);
}

@Override
public T updateById(T entity, ID entityId) {
    Optional<T> optional = abstractBaseRepository.findById(entityId);
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        return (T) abstractBaseRepository.save(entity);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(T entity) {
    abstractBaseRepository.delete(entity);
}

@Override
public void deleteById(ID entityId) {
    abstractBaseRepository.deleteById(entityId);
}
```

**GenericRepository:**
I created a basic repository class and because I needed a custom Query that was not supported by jpa, I had to add two more classes.
@Repository
public interface AbstractBaseRepository<T extends AbstractBaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>,AbstractBaseRepositoryCustom {

}

```
public interface AbstractBaseRepositoryCustom<T extends AbstractBaseEntity,ID extends Serializable> {
List<T> findAllByFiter(String textQuery);
```

}

```
public class AbstractBaseRepositoryCustomImpl<T extends AbstractBaseEntity,ID extends Serializable>  implements AbstractBaseRepositoryCustom {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;


@Override
public List findAllByFiter(String textQuery) {
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery(textQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

}

I don't know that the methods and wiring in my service class are correct. Is the repository installed correctly? Please help.

Comment: Don't know why you need it generic. I would not do it. Consider using AbstractAuditable: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractAuditable.html

Comment: @RobertNiestroj
I have different entities with some of the same behaviors that I don't want to be repeated